# Is there a predefined no-op Action in C#?

Tags: c#

Some functions expect an `Action` as an argument which I don't need in some cases.
Is there a predefined no-op `Action` comparable to the following?

```
Action NoOp = () => {};
```

Comment: There's nothing *pre-defined.* What you've done is best.